# How to decide the correct package to scan in jaxb2marshaller based on xsd

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-oxm

I am marshalling and unmarshalling using spring jaxb2marshaller. it is working for version 10 except now I have to support two different version (say version 01, and 10) of xsd schema. how to set jaxb2marshaller to scan package based on the xsd version. My parsing code is

```java
public void parseSampleFile(String fileLocation) throws FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {
    InputStream inputStream = getFilePathInputStream(fileLocation);
    XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    XMLReaderWithoutNamespace xmlStreamReader = new XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(xsr);
    StAXSource stAXSource = new StAXSource(xmlStreamReader);
    // skip to the first element to reach Document

    while (xmlStreamReader.hasNext() && !xmlStreamReader.isStartElement()) {
        xmlStreamReader.next();
    }

    while (xmlStreamReader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
        switch (xmlStreamReader.getLocalName()) {
            case "Hdr":
                header = (Header) jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(stAXSource);
                xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
                break;
            case "SomeInf":
                instruction = (Instruction) jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(stAXSource);
                xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
                break;
            default:
                xmlStreamReader.nextTag();
        }
    }
}
```

and I am setting jaxb2marshler in config file as

```java
@Bean
Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.version10.model");
    return jaxb2Marshaller;
}
```

Comment: Just scan both packages.